Swift Package Manager Transitive Local Dependency - package depends on local package, which is not supported
I have an iOS multi-repository app that uses cocoapods to sync multiple frameworks, I am trying to migrate to swift package manager whoever I'm facing some issue while trying to connect all dependencies, this is my architecture:
My app is in one repo and the rest of the packages are in a different repo, the package is a feature module, that is modularized internally to separate UI, Business Logic and  networking layer, each of them is a different package, here is a diagram that explains it better:

Since MultiFrameWorkPackage has a dependency on other frameworks I need to reference it locally, however when I try to fetch MultiFrameWorkPackage remotely from MyApp.xcodeproj I am getting following error:

package 'multiframeworks' is required using a revision-based
requirement and it depends on local package 'frameworka', which is not
supported

Is there any workaround to achieve this kind of architecture with SPM?
Here are code examples, you can even try running it:
Repo 1:
https://github.com/lalejzapata/MyMainApp
Repo 2:
https://github.com/lalejzapata/MultiFrameworks

Frameworks can’t have nested frameworks

Any documentation that confirms that? Any suggestion to achieve this architecture ? @loremipsum

It is somewhere in the framework documentation I don’t remember where. There is a workaround for macOS but it will not work with any other platform. Packages can have frameworks but frameworks can’t have them, they won’t get built. People ask this question on SO all the time as well so you should be able to find literal true about this over the years.

Found a way to achieve my goal, sharing just in case @loremipsum

Finally it worked, at first i wanted to have different Package.swift files and sync all of them as individual packages, I ended up having only 1 Package.swift that syncs all files and targets, here are some key points, and final Package.swift file:

When you have many nested folders make sure they are not named same as your package/target or xcode could ignore them, ej, avoid -> FrameworkA/FrameworkA/MyFile.swift.
Keep your path simple, since it is not allowed to have references outside of the root of a package, like path: ../FrameworkX.
Review the posted repos for full working example.

.
let package = Package(
name: "MultiFrameworksPackage",
products: [
    .library(
        name: "MultiFrameworksPackage",
        targets: ["MultiFrameworks", "FrameworkA", "FrameworkB"]
    )],
targets: [
    .target(
        name: "MultiFrameworks",
        dependencies: [
            "FrameworkA"
        ],
        path: "Sources"
    ),
    .target(
        name: "FrameworkA",
        dependencies: [
            "FrameworkB"
        ],
        path: "FrameworkA"
    ),
    .target(
        name: "FrameworkB",
        dependencies: [
        ],
        path: "FrameworkB"
    )
]

)
